# Be RESTful: performance issue?

Tags: performance, rest, mobile

Our mobile application uses a REST API to communicate with our server.
At the beginning I wanted to keep it RESTful, and keep using good practices. But:

- our API will never be public (only internal use)
- the application is more and more complex, and the number of requests are growing a lot

I have observed that public API from big services are not really RESTful, because it's hard to respect all constraints.

So do you think instead of making 5 requests to retrieve some data, I can make only one request, then parse the json on the client side?
It breaks an important REST rule, but that would significantly improve performance on the mobile application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Being RESTful by itself provides almost no benefit. The benefits of REST come from its individual properties (statelessness, client-server, resource-based), but not from being completely RESTful (or from using that word). You can pick the most important properties of REST, implement them, and not do the rest (no pun intended).

For example you don't need good URLs and meaningful verbs for your internal API. They are aethetic, but do not help you be more productive. Example: SOAP-based web-services do away with some of the less important REST principles but keep some of the good ones. Webservices are are productive technology, which is what counts.

You should probably use a middleware package for your internal API based on some standard protocols like WS-* and SOAP. A web-services framework solves the RPC-part of your internal API. You don't need to create/parse URLs and you don't need to deal with serialization.

Comment: And what do you think, as an alternative, to batch requests? (http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2013/06/5-ways-to-make-your-mobile-apps-faster-with-the-chatter-rest-api.html) Many topics exist about that, but I cannot extract a clear explanation if it is correct or not.

Comment: Batching is a useful concept. The blog post you have linked to seems to show an automated way to process batch requests. You can also do it manually, though. In some systems I have built we were forced to create a special batch API that clients could call to retrieve all data at once that was needed for a specific view. We did it for performance reasons, which is a valid reason.